# Button To Perform 2 Actions VIA PHP POST

Tags: php, html, function, button

I have this PHP script that performs two functions:

1. Increases the count in an XML tag of prayer_warriors by 1.
2. Sends a push notification to the proper user.

In my app, I can POST, and all the functions of the script get carried out.  The script code is:

```
<?php
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
 $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
 $title = $_POST['title'];
 $deviceToken = $_POST['iostoken'];
$xml = simplexml_load_file("/Test.xml") or die("Not loaded!\n");


$responses = $xml->xpath("//channel/item[title = '$title' and first_name = '$first_name' and last_name = '$last_name']/prayer_warriors");
$responses[0][0] = $responses[0] + 1;
echo($responses);
$xml->asXML("Test.xml");  
// Put your device token here (without spaces):

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'Passphrase';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'Someone just pledged to pray for you!';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);  
?>
```

I use the following to POST to this PHP from a web page.  It will trigger the part to send a push notification, but will NOT increase the prayer_warrior count by 1.

```
$title = $item->title;
$first_name = $item->first_name;
$last_name = $item->last_name;
$iostoken = $item->iostoken;
Echo "<form action=\"http://Url.php\" method=\"post\">";
Echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"first_name\" value=".$first_name.">";
Echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"last_name\" value=".$last_name.">";
Echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"title\" value=".$title.">";
Echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"iostoken\" value=".$iostoken.">";

 Echo  "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Pledge to pray\" />";
Echo "</form>";
```

Any ideas why it would do this?

Comment: PHP doesn't have "buttons". Figure out the html to accomplish what you want, then have PHP spit out that html.

Comment: I know it doesn't have buttons...but I can't just randomly program buttons, it needs to be one button per item that the PHP parses from the XML, and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: you're alreading parsing "per item" and outputting data from each of those items. adding some more html to generate a button is simple. And if you're doing web-based PHP, you should already know how to build a form and submit it. So put it all together.

Comment: Ok, if I'm asking a specific question, answering it with "you should already know how" is not an acceptable answer.  Don't you think if I already knew how, I would not be asking it?

Comment: I'm just pointing out that you already know the answer, but since you can't see the forest for the trees, you don't realize you already know it. just because the data's coming from xml doesn't change how you'd build an html form. your form's data could come from a file, a db, hardcoded, it could hand-entered by an army of chinese slaves. in the end you still have JUST an html form. data submissions from that form will work exactly the same no matter how the form was built.

Comment: See edit to the original post

Comment: Just add hidden inputs to each form; the value of those hidden inputs can be whatever you like for each iteration and will be posted when the submit button in the form is pressed.

Comment: Ok, @SharkofMirkwood I added this, and it is partially carrying out my PHP, but only half of the PHP is being carried out.  I know the script works because it all functions from my app that also uses POST

Comment: You pull out an xml attribute and increment it, but that increment is done on a completely separate value. you don't actually push that new value back into the DOM, so when you save the xml, all you're doing is saving the original un-changed copy. Plus, for this kind of thing, you really should be using a database. you risk multiple parallel processes stomping all over the .xml file and trashing your updates.

Comment: XML is what I know how to do, never used a database before at all, and the app is all built for doing it this way.  When I run the POST from app it increases the count and saves the xml.  Do I need to do something different in the code I posted?

Comment: @MarcB if that code is missing something that keeps it from writing the new value, then why does the exact same code work when ran from iOS?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to write to a different file than you're reading from.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("/Test.xml") or die("Not loaded!\n");
                            ^
```

Try changing

```
$xml->asXML("Test.xml");
```

To

```
$xml->asXML("/Test.xml");
```

With error logging in case permissions are preventing you from updating the file

```
if(false === $xml->asXML("/Test.xml")) {
  die('Could not update XML!');
}
```

Comment: The issue is that when I run this PHP from app, it DOES save the XML, but when I run it from the web, it is not.  So changing the format of the saved name will have no effect here, as it is working in one circumstance but not the other.

Comment: is it posssible that you have a permissions issue? i.e. the user you run it as from the command line has write permission for `Test.xml` but the web server does not? If so, try doing a `chmod +777 Test.xml`

Comment: It has 0644 permission on it, @fuzzytree

Comment: 644 means only the owner is allowed to write to the file. who is the owner of the file?

Comment: I own the file, but it just doesn't make sense that the app would somehow have permission to do so, even users besides me have been able to write to it.

Comment: Ok....I changed permission to 775 for the Test.xml file.  I then ran this script from my computer.  It once again sent a push notification to my phone for the entry I clicked on, but did NOT increase the count.  It did, however, show that the file had been modified at the time I clicked the button.

So, for some reason, it is now saving the file, but without the increase to the item I asked it to.

Comment: @user717452 just to be clear, you're able to increase the count in some cases but not others?

Comment: There are two methods I use to do this.  One is just on a website using a form, and the other is in a native iOS app.  From the app, I just use a POST method for the PHP, and it sends the notification out to the iOS device that posted that request, and increases count by 1.  On the web, it sends the notification to the iOS device that made the request, but does not increase the count.  Using same PHP for both instances.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56133/discussion-between-fuzzytree-and-user717452).

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is in the `simplexml_load_file("/Test.xml");`.
What you want is `simplexml_load_file("Test.xml");`, because "/Test.xml" is equivalent to `your_site_here.com/Test.xml`. Or it might be equivalent to `SYSTEM_ROOT/Test.xml`
If you prefix the filename with a `/`, then the file/file-path is relative to the site-root/directory root. `./` and no prefix are relative to the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

Start by investigating this code:

```
$responses[0][0] = $responses[0] + 1;
```

maybe change it to

```
var_dump($responses);
var_dump($responses[0][0]);
$responses[0][0]++;
var_dump($responses[0][0]);
```

If the second time $responses[0][0] is echo'd and it has a value = +1 the old value, you know it isn't an XPath issue, and it is something else to do with the post or something. Make sure $xml is in the payload if it needs to be.

One thing I realized is you call this line of code:

```
$xml->asXML("Test.xml");
```

Should that be $xml->asXML($responses) ? If it must be a file, I feel as though the above line is reading from the file in the state before $responses was not incremented. Try writing the new $responses data to that file after incrementing prayer_warrior, but before setting $xml->asXML.

Comment: Right, the desired effect is that it 'opens' the xml, and finds the item matching the title first name and last name, increments prayer_warriors by 1, and then saves it in the same location with the same name, effectively overwriting the original.

Comment: Yes I see that but I don't see where you are performing the over-write, you only change the variable $responses without actually saving it to the xml file

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to case sensitive issue.Check if the file name is Test or test

Answer (score 0):

After `echo($responses);` add:

```
$xml->path->to->prayer_warriors = $responses[0] + 1;
$xml->asXML('/Test.xml');
```

Answer (score 0):

It smells of missing htmlencoding in your web form as you possibly insert invalid values directly into the form without encoding them. It may also be a character encoding issue.

Read more on http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

You could try something like

```
$title = htmlentities($item->title);
$first_name = htmlentities($item->first_name);
$last_name = htmlentities($item->last_name);
$iostoken = htmlentities($item->iostoken);
```

And maybe try adding encoding to your form

```
Echo "<form action=\"http://Url.php\" method=\"POST\" accept-charset=\"UTF-8\">";
```